# Sequelize - findOne().success() is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js, sequelize.js

I am following the passport.js doc in order to create a LocalStrategy using Sequelize as ORM for my postgres database. However, during authentification, doing `User.findOne(...).success(function(user){...]});` in my login.js module returns `undefined`. What am I doing wrong?

user.js:

```
var pg = require('pg');
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');

var sequelize = new Sequelize('database', 'username', 'password', {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 5432,
    dialect: 'postgres'
});

var User = sequelize.define('users', {
    username: Sequelize.STRING,
    password: Sequelize.STRING

});

User.sync();

module.exports = User;
```

my login.js (router)

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;


passport.serializeUser(function(user, done){
    done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done){
    console.log(id)
    User.findById(id, function(err, user){
        done(err, user);
    });
});

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
    function(username, password, done){
        var User = require('../models/user');
        User.find({where:{username: username, password: password}}).success(function(user){
            if(!user) {
                return done(null, false, {message: 'Nom d\'usager incorrect.' });
            }
            if (!user.validPassword(password)) {
                return done(null, false, { message: 'Mot de passe incorrect.' });
            }
            return done(null, user);
        });
    }
));

router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', { successRedirect: '/decoupage',
                                                       failureRedirect: '/login',
                                                       failureFlash: true })
);


module.exports = router;
```

Comment: You should accept the @robertklep answer wich is correct.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Sequelize uses a modified version of the [`bluebird`](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird) promise library, which doesn't have a `.success()` function.

Instead, use `.then()` (which also follows the [Promises/A+](https://promisesaplus.com/) standard):

```
User.find(options).then(
  function(user) { ... },
  function(err) { ... }
);
```

Comment: @abhishek, Current versions of `sequelize` use the stock version of `bluebird`. To catch errors use `.catch` or `.error`. Documentation can be found [here](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api-reference.html).